# Using await in node.js

Tags: node.js, async-await

I have a function that reads files in a directory and pushes their name into an array. But every time I try to print the array, it's empty because the code does not wait for the function to finish, even though I used await that suppose to make the code wait for the function.

here is the code:

```
let filesToMove = [];

async function readFiles() {
  const testFolder = "./files_to_move/";

  fs.readdir(testFolder, (err, files) => {
    files.forEach((file) => {
        filesToMove.push(file);
      console.log("done");
    });
  });
}

async function printFiles() {
  files = await readFiles();

  console.log(filesToMove.length);
  filesToMove.forEach((item) => {
      console.log(item);
  });
}
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using callback method which doesn't waits to finish.

So solution use `'fs/promises'` with `await`.

```js
 const fsp = require('fs/promises')

//...

 const files =  await fsp.readdir(testFolder)
```

Answer (score 0):

You using callback in `readFile` function. You need to use the async version for `readdir`.

```
  const { readdir } = require('fs/promises')

let filesToMove = [];

async function readFiles() {
  const testFolder = "./files_to_move/";
   
  const files = await readdir(testFolder)
  files.forEach((file) => {
     filesToMove.push(file);
     console.log("done");
  });
}

async function printFiles() {
  await readFiles();

  console.log(filesToMove.length);
 filesToMove.forEach((item) => {
    console.log(item);
 });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
for (const file of files) {
  filesToMove.push(file);
}
```

I think forEach does not work with files.
I hope this will be helpful for you. Thanks.

Comment: If you aren't sure what the problem is, then maybe you shouldn't answer. `files` is an array and `forEach` works just fine.